# Check if $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2-n^2}$ is continuous and differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

> Check if $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2-n^2}$ is continuous and differentiable function
>   $$ D = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$$

### My try

$$\frac{1}{x^2-n^2} \text{~~~} 1/n^2$$ so $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2-n^2}$$ converges (pointwise) as well
$$ \sup_{x \in D} \left| \frac{1}{n^2 - x^2} - 0  \right| =  \sup_{x \in D} \left| \frac{1}{n^2 - x^2} \right| = \infty  $$
but I don't know how to continue that way..

Comment: Did the problem say to find the domain of convergence?  

For a general theory, see bottom of page 17 and on, in https://books.google.com/books?id=SlpwANmq5xQC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: What's $D{}{}{}{}$? Why do you say that the two expressions in your first line are asymptotically equivalent, and where are you claiming they are?

Comment: $x$ is constant there and we have $n^2$ in denominator. We can find limit of fraction first by second but it is trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is not an integer  then the inequality $|x^{2}-n^{2}| \geq n^{2}-x^{2}$ shows that the series is uniformly convergent in some neighborhood of $x$ and hence the sum is continuous at $x$. Apply the same argument to the differentiated series to conclude that the sum is in fact differentiable at any point which is not an integer as well as at $0$.

Comment: so there I should calculate derivative $2$ times?

Comment: @trolley Only once. Use the following theorem: if $f_n$'s are differentiable and$\sum f_n$ and $\sum f_n'$ converge uniformly on $[a,b]$ then $\sum f_n  $ is diffferentiable (and its derivative is $\sum f_n'$).

Comment: I know but to examine uniform convergence I should calculate $f_n ' (x) = (2 x)/(n^2 - x^2)^2$. And then when I calculating supremum $ \sup_{x \in D} \left| (2 x)/(n^2 - x^2)^2 - 0  \right| $ I should find bound for this expression

Comment: Use the inequality $(n^{2}-x^{2})^{2} \geq (n^{2}-C)^{2}$ for $|x| \leq C$ and compare with the series $\sum \frac {2C} {(n^{2}-C)^{2}}$. No need to compute any maximums.

Comment: Very interesting observation, thanks @Kavi !

Comment: @avan1235 Use M-test to see that the given series as well as the differentiated series converge uniformly on any closed interval not containing any integer.